# syntax error missing ';' before 'type'

Tags: c, syntax-error

I have this error:

> error C2143 syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

Coming from this block of code:

```
int GetValidatedInteger(int Min, int Max);

int main (void)
{
    // Student number //
    int GetstudentID();

    int studentID=0;
    {
        int studentID;
        printf("Plase enter a student  Number <101-999>" );
        scanf("%d", &studentID);
        return studentID;
        fflush(stdin);

        return (studentID);
    }
```

I have no idea what it means. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: So, what line of code is the error on??? This code won't even compile.  Please post the complete code, and formatted properly.

Comment: The block (error) is not in the source code you provided

Comment: why there is a bracket after `int studentID=0;`?

Comment: Why was a `}` edited into the code? Why was `int` changed to `bbint`? The fact that the `}` was missing may have been (part of) the problem. By changing the posted code without knowing if that was OP's actual code or a copy/paste error, the question is potentially invalidated. Just because code in a question doesn't compile doesn't mean it should be edited such that it compiles.

Comment: @ajp15243 Yeah I just did a rollback; that edit should not have been done, for the very reasons you gave.

Comment: Taken the original code snippet from the original post and prettied it up for readability.

Comment: @jessehouwing Wasn't quite the original code, it was the code from right after the erroneous edit (revision #3) :/. Edit: Huzzah! It looks good and correct now!

Comment: @ajp15243 Looking at the revision history, jessehouwing edited the version I rolled back to (#2)

Comment: @DennisMeng Interesting, the revision history from earlier clearly showed the "bad edits" from revision #3 in there, but now they don't. Seems he's fixed it for good this most recent time tho.

Comment: @ajp15243: [Agreed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141749/167210).

Comment: @OldProgrammer: "*This code won't even compile*" -- Yeah, I think that's the whole point.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do.. And it should be outside of main function.

```
int GetstudentID()
{
    int studentID;
    printf("Plase enter a student  Number <101-999>" );
    scanf("%d", &studentID);
    return studentID;
}
```